Getting Last columns range values when there are empty cells in Google Sheets
The master table is rows 1-7
-It is growing by an additional column each week/period.
-The index and counta solutions that I have looked at are all for non empty cell applications. Which would work if each empty cell had 0 or another value in it.  My situation has blank cells throughout the table

rows 11-16 is an example of the results that I am looking to produce.

pulling out the last column which will change each period.
_ pulling out the total of the last 3 columns which will also change each period


Please [edit] to include more of your weeks. It isn't clear what the challenge is.

I just want to make sure that I understand this post correctly, what you wanted is to show the last records based on the chain of tables above? I want to understand if your items will change, also if it is possible for your table to continue as it is right now without skipping a column?  Can you clarify this as well "I tried Index, counta, arrays etc...Empty cells are the road block" so the community will understand the limitation for your project.

Consider providing input and expected output as plain text table in the question. Click here to create a table easily, which are easy to copy/paste.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question useless for others or images, which are hard to copy. Also, note that your email address can also be accessed by the public, if you share Google files.

Your answer is solid...  It's my deployment which is faulty. thanks for the kind assistance

Clear the existing data from A10:E16 and put the following formula in A10.
It will generate the two tables and the results.
No Headings Row
This formula will work whether there is a headings row or not.
=LET(range,A2:Z7, labels,INDEX(range,,1), 
  array,FILTER(range, 
    BYCOL(range, LAMBDA(c, COUNTA(c)>0))), 
  three,CHOOSECOLS(array,
     SEQUENCE(3,1,COLUMNS(array)-2)),
  IFNA(VSTACK(
    HSTACK("Last Recorded Week",,,
      "Last 3 Week Period"), 
    HSTACK(labels, INDEX(three,,3),,
    labels, BYROW(three, LAMBDA(r, SUM(r)))))))


It uses BYROW to check which columns have at least one value in any row from 2 to 7. That information is used to FILTER range to remove empty columns and the result is stored in array.
three stores the last 3 columns of array
Finally the results are returned:

The first column is labels which are your part names.
Second column is the last week's numbers taken from the last column of three
Then a blank column is added followed by another instance of labels.
The last column is the 3 week total, returned by passing three into a BYROW function whose LAMBDA formula sums each row in turn.



Headings Row
This formula will only work if there is a headings row.
=LET(range,A2:Z7, hdg,A1:Z1, 
  labels,INDEX(range,,1), 
  three,CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(range,hdg<>""),
    SEQUENCE(1,3, COUNTA(hdg)-2)),
  IFNA(VSTACK(
    HSTACK("Last Recorded Week",,,
      "Last 3 Week Period"), 
    HSTACK(labels, INDEX(three,,3),,
      labels, BYROW(three, LAMBDA(r, SUM(r)))))))

Same as the previous formula except that array is omitted because three is calculated differently:

CHOOSECOLS array_range argument is range filtered to remove columns that don't have a heading.
SEQUENCE uses COUNTA on the headings to determine the total number of columns.


I used this option   =LET(range,MainInvE, labels,INDEX(range,,1), array,FILTER(range, BYCOL(range, LAMBDA(c, COUNTA(c)>0))), ...
I  got this error
The value of parameter 2 of function CHOOSECOLS cannot be zero
Here’s what I have done
• Used named range
• Used the Let formula on a sheet of its own in the sameworkbook
• Tested in the sample/ everything works perfectly
• Plugged it into the actual sheet
o Returns the 40plus items (Labels) in Col A & D perfectly
o Returns the  above value error in B & E
I cannot figure what adjustments need making or why

The error points to a problem with SEQUENCE(3,1,COLUMNS(array)-2) which likely points to an issue with array. To troubleshoot, turn the last statement of LET into a variable, by adding a name before the last IFNA, (e.g. test,IFNA(VSTACK...) then, insert a comma before the last closing parenthesis of the full formula, and then between that comma and the last parenthesis, you can place any variable or a one-off calculation without affecting the formula. You can put ,test) at the end to check the current result or ,array) to see what it returns or ,SEQUENCE(3,1,COLUMNS(array)-2)) etc.

I've taken a different approach, it seems to work for me.  Based on this sheet:
A screenshot of the source table and output
in 'B10' and copied down to B16: =indirect("R" & row()-9 & "C" & counta($1:$1),false)
in 'E10': =let(label, indirect("R1C" & counta(1:1),false) , week,right(label,len(label)-5)*1,"Weeks " & week-2 & "-" & week)
In 'E11' and copied down to E16: =sum(let(week, counta($1:$1), srcRow, match(D11,$A$1:$A$7, 0), indirect("R" & srcRow & "C" & week-2  & ":R" & srcRow & "C" & week, false)))
if the lable 'Week 4' is deleted in Row 1 you'll see the 3 week figures change and the weeks that are summarised there.  Additionally, adding further weeks will work as I believe you require.
